# Finding a limit of a two variable function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Find the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,2)}\sqrt{y^2-4}\ln(5-x^2-y^2)$.

Apologize if this is too basic. I know that $\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln(x)=0$. Is this enough to determine the limit even in the two variable case? I wasn't able to rule out existence of the limit with different paths. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The limit doesn't exist because if $y<2$, the square root is undefined. We might consider $y \to 2+$, but then the log term will be undefined.